# C# custom attribute how to change target class property

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm try to find a solution to realize decrypt/encrypt when access a class property by get/set.

I had researched something about C# custom attribute, but seemimgly it can't work, so I want to know whether it's impossible to change the class property by attribute.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class MyAttribute : Attribute
    {
        // How to change the tragetClass.Name when access by get/set
    }

    public class TargetClass
    {
        [MyAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Only with IL manipulation as far as I know. The getters and setters are readonly (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod)). But as already mentioned it is possible to manipulate the IL through attributes with additional libraries. I'd just stick with coding the logic manually inside the getter and setters (if your really need it, otherwise I would stay away from much logic in getters/setters).

Comment: No they cannot, as attributes are just data, not an executable code. That is in data vs code, data cannot change anything, but data can guide what/how an external code can make a change.